# How to keep my selected menu open in my side bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html look's like this below and I am also using Bootstrap. I would like the menu to stay open on my sidebar, after i have selected it.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="treeview-menu" id="submenu_toggle">
  <li>
    <a href="tickets.php">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Inbox
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tickets.php?status=assigned">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Mine 
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tickets.php?status=overdue">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Overdue 
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tickets.php?status=closed">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Closed
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to ask please write in brief whats your question?

Comment: How to keep open my selected menu in side bar. I want when i click on mine link than it should be open and selected, And same thing for other links.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not a one page application, consider using this. You are required to load this js & css on every page in menu item.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <ul class="treeview-menu" id="submenu_toggle">
      <li>
        <a href="tickets.php">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Inbox
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="tickets.php?status=assigned">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Mine
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="tickets.php?status=overdue">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Overdue
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="tickets.php?status=closed">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o sub_menu_fa"></i>Closed
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {   
           var url = window.location.href; //get current page url        
             $(".treeview-menu i").each(function() { 
                if (url == (this.href)) {
                       $(this).addClass("active"); //add active class to matched LIst item
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
    .active{
      border-bottom:1px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
     $(function() { 
    // for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab', for bootstrap 2 use 'shown' in the next line
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        // save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    // go to the latest tab, if it exists:
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: I have edited your post to look the code meaningful and neat. Review my edit. Thanks :)